# Restoring mail from backup after hard disk died

Tags: mail.app, data-recovery

The hard disk on my iMac (Mac OS X 10.5.8) died, and after getting it replaced I have been trying to restore my files from backup.  The backup I have is just a copy of my user directory.  I copied the following files from backup to their corresponding location in my user directory before starting up Mail:

- Library/Mail
- Library/Mail Downloads
- Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist
- Library/Preferences/comp.apple.mail.searchhistory.plist

Going into Mail, I see my email accounts, and I can look at the lists of email messages... but when I click on the message to see it, there's no message content.

The strange thing is that when I look in INBOX.mbox/Messages for the mail account, I can see the email message files (.emlx files), and opening any of these files I can verify that the message contents are there.  But Mail won't show the message contents.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

**UPDATE:** Thanks, everyone, for the feedback. It appears that just before my hard drive died I got some files corrupted, and that was the source of the problem. I tried restoring from a backup taken one day earlier, and that worked perfectly.

Comment: Are you sure you copied these into your User account's folders (/Users/yourusername/Library), rather than the system? (/System/Library or /Library,)  also, it might be a permissions problem, though that's less likely if you did in fact *copy* these folders.

Comment: Yes, I copied them into my User account's folders.  And yes, it was copy and paste using Finder.

Answer (score 2):

The email index probably needs to be rebuilt.  Last option on the Mailbox Menu.

(And just in case, you do still have your backup, right?)  :)